# Weird error: not found #dependent variable in eval(predvars, data, env)

Tags: r, regression, predict

I am having a weird error when trying to make prediction from my model.

My original dataset is a discrete choice experiment where doctors evaluate a set of patients with different characteristics and make a treatment choice.

The structure of my data is like this:

```
>str(dcefull2)
'data.frame':   350 obs. of  28 variables:
 $ id               : Factor w/ 25 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ choice           : Factor w/ 3 levels "stop","half",..: 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ response         : Factor w/ 2 levels "Good response",..: 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ resist_profile   : Factor w/ 3 levels "MDR-TB","MDR-TB + PZA + EMB resis",..: 3 2 2 3 3 2 1 2 3 3 ...
 $ ambu_regimen     : Factor w/ 2 levels "BPaLM","Standard": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ expo_his         : Factor w/ 2 levels "No exposure",..: 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ resist_prob      : num  2.8 0.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 1.8 2.8 0.8 2.8 0.8 ...
 $ cred_interval    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Wide","Narrow": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
```

I fitted an ordered logistic model with the choice (ordinal variable with 3 categories) as a function of patient characteristics.

```
random_model_off3 <- clmm2(choice ~ response + resist_prob*resist_profile + resist_prob*ambu_regimen + resist_prob*expo_his + resist_prob*cred_interval, random = id,  data=dcefull2, Hess = TRUE, nAGQ = 10)
```

I then created a new dataset with all independent variables as in the original dataset. I varied the values of the variable 'resist_prob' and 'cred_interval', other variables I kept one fixed value.
The structure of my new data is like this:

```
>str(newdat2)
'data.frame':   2002 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ response      : Factor w/ 1 level "Good response": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ resist_profile: Factor w/ 1 level "MDR-TB": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ cred_interval : Factor w/ 2 levels "Wide","Narrow": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ ambu_regimen  : Factor w/ 1 level "BPaLM": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ expo_his      : Factor w/ 1 level "No exposure": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ resist_prob   : num  0 0 0.004 0.004 0.008 0.008 0.012 0.012 0.016 0.016 ...
```

I used function predict() to make prediction of probability of each treatment choice for each row.

```
predict(random_model_off3, newdata = newdat2)
```

Then I received this error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'choice' not found

I found it very weird because "choice" is my dependent variable. I cannot find any similar issues and solution on the internet.
I would very appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you add a reproducible sample of data using `dput()`?

Comment: What happens if you add a variable called `choice`?  It might be that the test in the predict method is looking for something it doesn't need.  Why not give it something?

Comment: The documentation says this: `For clmm2 fits this means predictions that are controlled for the observed value of the random effects.`

Comment: @Mohanasundaram so it means that I could only make prediction based on the original dataset?